# How to display multiple images from api call

Tags: reactjs, image, api, async-await

[image code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfTaI.jpg)
I need to display some images from api. I am using axios to get images. ids of images is coming from another api one by one. if i use map it will show nothing . I want to show all images as soon as api send the id. map pnly works on loading i guess.

Comment: Please check this guide on [why should you not upload image of code or Error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ListView in React

example:

```
  <ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={data => (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          source={{ uri: imageSource }}
          style={styles.img}
        />
        <Text>{data}</Text>
      </View>)}
  />
```

Comment: i am having issue with calling map on array. map is working on an empty array. how to make map load only when array has any element?

Comment: can you please post your code ?.

Comment: you can check with the array length. if the array length is greater than one  then you can execute your map else return null or set UI.

Comment: added as image link in question. Like i don't want to not show if array length is zero. I want to wait for api response when array length is greater than zero. and then load.

Comment: then you've to use async await or Promise. by using that you can manage as you want.

Comment: can u check code image please.

Comment: Sure you're doing it in the wrong way. you've set an array in your state and then you can map successfully. can you share your data array after getting the all data from api

Comment: i am trying not to share api and api response but i am able to display image for data[5] ..like for any specific index but not in map coz when map is called array is empty.